# Lotus script dblook up

Tags: lotus, lotusscript, lotus-formula

i use this code to my combo box `@Unique(@DbColumn("":"nocache";@DbName;"view";2))` to call the value in a view, now my question is this, if the value of the combo box is human in another combo box will show all the name of the human listed in the other view.

Comment: why can't you check it yourself? also what you ask is not clear (at least for me)

Comment: Please try re-stating your question.  It's not clear what you want to see happen, and it's not clear what you have tried so far.  Also, please say why you have included the LotusScript tag. You have shown only Lotus formula code.

Comment: sorry for my still of explaining things it hard for me to meet the exact explanation, for most people.

Comment: hmm, i have two combo box the one have content 1 2 3, when i select 1 in my combo box 1. combo box 2 give the content boy girl. and when i select 2 in combo box 1, combo box 2 will change the content to dog or cat, but the value of the content will look up to the view that i pointing to.

Comment: Can you add some images or screen shots? JPG please.

Comment: [here is the picture and explaination.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwZtZNJMkf32cXFPTV82WWZtVk0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: i upload the picture in google drive.

Comment: Badly stated, but I think he is trying to figure out how to implement observable dependencies w/ his combo boxes. e.g. what he selects in one combo box would change options in another combo box.

Comment: yes sir, that's right

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question, although it's still some confusing.

Following your explanation in the comments, you need a categorized view:

```
>Value 1
        Boy
        Girl
>Value 2
        Dog
        Cat
```

The view could be called "view_by_value_x"

**In the first combobox** with a name like "field_combo_1", you should write this code in the `Properties` window, `Options by formula`

```
@DbColumn("":"nocache"; ""; "view_by_value_x"; 1)
```

**In the second combobox**, you should write this in the same place

```
@DbLookup("":"nocache"; ""; "view_by_value_x"; field_combo_1; 2)
```

Don't forget to enable, in the first combobox, the option `"Refresh fields on keyword change"`, and in the second combobox, the option `"Refresh choices on document refresh"`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you sir, sorry for the late reply I'm out for so long that's why.